# Backbone is not defined error

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Trying to create Backbone model and got error. I have added jquery, underscore and backbone but there is still error.

```js
var Alco =  Backbone.Model.extend({
 defaults: {
  price: 100,
  name: "Vodka",
  description: "I don't know",
  img: "http://xo.kz/media/images/products/2016/02/i1g1_small_13.png"
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css">
 <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <title> AlcoWiki </title>
</head>
<body>
 <script src="js/jquery-1.12.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is your js inside of `main.js`? If so, you need to load backbone before it.

Comment: You're also loading 2 different versions of jQuery, which might cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if all referenced files are there, and loading, then this should work

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainstyle.css">
   <title> AlcoWiki </title>
</head>
<body>
   <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/backbone.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```